# NSPredicate using Core Data entity's attribute

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, core-data, nspredicate

I have person and team entities, where many people can belong to a team. I am trying to create an NSPredicate using the person's number and the team's name. So, this request will check to see if there is already a person in Core Data who has the number N and belongs to team T. But, I have not been able to make the predicate work so that I can get the TEAM's attribute for comparison.

My current predicate is as follows:

```
request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(team.name LIKE %@) AND (number == %@)", [[personInfo objectForKey:PLAYS_FOR] name], [personInfo objectForKey:PERSON_NUMBER]];
```

It seems to me that the first part of the predicate (team.name LIKE %@) is where the issue is at. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(name ==[c] %@) AND (number == %@)", [[personInfo objectForKey:PLAYS_FOR] name], [personInfo objectForKey:PERSON_NUMBER]];
```

Comment: Hmm that doesn't do it. I think the problem is with getting the "name" attribute from the "team" entity in "team.name LIKE %@". Is this not the correct way to get the object's property in the predicate format?

Answer (score 0):

you need a relationship between your team entity and player entity.

1 player 1 team, 1 team many players.

thats why add a relation in players enity and check **player.team == %@ AND player.number == %d**.

Comment: Let me explain a little further what I'm trying to do. I have the player data in an NSDictionary, now I wish to see if there is a Player in CoreData that already shares this data (has the same number and belongs to the same team).
So I wish to query the database using some loose data that was entered by the user.

Comment: can you provide me keys of the dictionary?

Comment: Yeah it's just PLAYS_FOR and PERSON_NUMBER, where the dictionary is personInfo

Comment: [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"PLAYS_FOR == %@ AND number == %d", @"lackers", 12];

Comment: lemme know if you have Array containing dictionaries.